# Custom android plug-in, how to print log in android stuido

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, sbt-android-plugin

Custom android plug-in, how to print  log in android stuido

now i used System and Logger To no avail ，I want see the log in android stuido Event log view

System.out.println("Systemout:" + log);

Logger.getInstance("Logger").debug(log);

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by custom android plug-in, but to see the log events you can use

```
Log.d("tag","message");
```

This can be then read in the logcat under debug.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just to see the output in a console, you may want to use Log. This should be visible in logcat tab.

```
Log.d("tagName", "Message to be logged");
```